# Escape custom list of characters?

Tags: php

Howwdy SO!

My goal is to be able to show a list of files for the following path, using `glob()`:

```
$path = glob("/folder/subfolder/[Wow] File name - 01~12 [720p][Multiple Subtitle]/*");
```

Sadly, for this function to work correctly, I need to escape the following characters using a `\`:

```
? * [ ]
```

I could just do the following, obviously:

```
$path = str_replace('?','\?',$path);
$path = str_replace('*','\*',$path);
$path = str_replace('[','\[',$path);
// And so on...
```

But im concerned about clean code and, most importantly, speed..

Is there a better way to do this? Oh and I tought this was worth mentioning... `quotemeta();` almost escapes all the characters I need, with a few exceptions sadly. Is there a way to tell this function or a similar one to escape the characters I want?

Comment: "most importantly, speed" --- 3 function calls is nothing compared to at least one syscall + a bunch of IO operations. PS: `str_replace` also accepts arrays.

Comment: And a mandatory: every performance optimisation must be preceded with profiling/benchmarking.

Comment: @zerkms I was simply wondering if there was any way to make this look cleaner, cause obviously this is not the best way imo

Comment: Yep, and I added a `PS` (probably after you first read it)

Comment: str_replace does accept arrays, but I can only replace ?, *, ,[ ,] to a single thing

Comment: It accepts arrays for both arguments

Comment: @zerkms you are right.. eheh..

Comment: You are going to the filesystem, the slowest thing in the server.  Performance is clearly not a concern.  With that said, there is a PHP solution for what you need. See [escapeshellcmd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)